# Possibility to complete current statement with anonymous implementation

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut (or menu entry) in IntelliJ IDEA to complete the current statement with an anonymous implementation. To make this more understandable:

I type something like: `view.setOnClickListener(` and would now like a shortcut to get the completion to:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        <<new caret position>>
    }
});
```

Assuming that the `setOnClickListener` method would accept one parameter of type `OnClickListener`. I don't care if there are already implementations of `OnClickListener` I would just like the very basic type (or interface) that is expected as an anonymous inner class.

So do anyone know if there is a possibility for this in IntelliJ IDEA, without the need of typing `new OnClickListener` (with auto completion) yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to write:

`view.setOnClickListener(new` + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

This will bring up a list of alternatives but since you used the [Smart Type Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html) (instead of [Basic Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html) which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) you will have the one that fits best at the top.

So now just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the rest will be filled in for you.

You save some writing but still have to at least write `new` in order for it to work.

> `Smart Type code completion` filters the suggestion list and includes only those types that are applicable to the current context.